# Error when trying to push sf::Texture* into std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, sfml

I'm working on a C++ project that uses SFML and lua
The thing is when I tried to push the texture pointer that I loaded it crashes.

Here's my code

```
    sf::Texture* tex = new sf::Texture;
    if(!tex->loadFromFile(lua_tostring(L, -1))) std::cout << "Failed to load texture!" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Got here!" << std::endl;
    try{
        p.tex_auras.push_back(tex);
    }catch(std::invalid_argument& e){
        std::cout << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
```

If I comment out the push_back thingy, everything was fine. Also, the code spits out **Got here!** once and if tried checking the tex->loadFromFile() to see if it fails, it didn't. When I debug the code it seems to happen in the std::vector::push_back

```
        void push_back(const value_type &__x) {
            if (this->_M_impl._M_finish != this->_M_impl._M_end_of_storage) {          <<== HERE ==
                _Alloc_traits::construct(this->_M_impl, this->_M_impl._M_finish,
                        __x);
                ++this->_M_impl._M_finish;
            } else
                _M_realloc_insert(end(), __x);
        }
```

#### Edit

```
typedef std::vector<sf::Texture*> Textures;
// The textures was initialized in a class as such
class Player {
public:
     // Just like that
     Textures tex_auras;
}
```

I don't know what's going on

Comment: What you have described strongly implies that `p.tex_auras` is not a valid `std::vector` object that you can push into. Where exactly is that vector declared in relation to this code, and how is it initialized? Please provide a [mcve]. On a side note, `push_back()` will never throw a `std::invalid_argument` exception. If anything, it can only throw `std::bad_alloc` if the push fails to allocate memory, or *maybe* `std::length_error` if an array reallocation would exceed the vector's `max_size()`.

Comment: I don't think you're showing enough code.  The only thing that will crash your program while calling `std::vector::push_back` is if there is no memory left and you're not handling `std::bad_alloc` exception.  I would say that `p` or `p.tex_auras` probably isn't a valid object in memory.  Or you have stack or heap corruption somewhere.

Comment: I've updated the question. Shouldn't be a problem cause it's not a pointer. It will automatically called the default constructor though when I created the player @RemyLebeau

Comment: "*Shouldn't be a problem cause it's not a pointer*" - just because something is not a pointer does not mean it can't be invalid, such as if memory is corrupted, or you are using a dangling reference, etc. Your update is still not a [mcve] since it doesn't show how `p` is declared and initialized.

Comment: I'd recommend `-fsanitize=address` to see what quick results that gives and adding that info to the MRE if you can't figure it out from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the player is NULL in the first place after I loaded the userdata from lua. I'm on the wrong stack index

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather post this as a comment, but I don't have enough rep.

While this won't completely solve the error, you might be able to avoid the crash if you changed the `catch` block to `}catch(std::exception& e) {` instead of `}catch(std::invalid_argument& e){`.  The exception being thrown might not be an invalid_argument exception, and catching all exceptions works better as a catch-all.  Assuming this works, you could also end up with a more informative error message and thus a better idea of what is going wrong.